# Linux: Share my hard drive on the web

Tags: hard-drive, web

Is there a simple turnkey app for Linux that makes a folder, say my user directory, accessible on the public internet with a nice browser-based file management interface?

I'm looking for a smart, reliable solution that understands when this PC loses internet connection and seamlessly crosses whatever firewalls are in the way -- in other words, that just works.

Comment: *why in the **world** would you want to do that?!*

Comment: What do you mean by "understands when this PC loses internet connection", and what do you want to happen if you loss the connection?

Comment: bryan -- meaning, start working again when the net connection returns without requiring user intervention.

Answer (score 2):

Needs some setup, but [owncloud](http://owncloud.org/)  might fit the bill - they suggest using [pagekite](http://pagekite.net/wiki/) with it - owncloud allows web and webdav access to files, and pagekite allows for reverse proxying.

Personally i'd rather use something like dropbox to have file access when my server is down or other malfunctions happen, but that's vaguely off the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/benefits.aspx) provides file transfers and does not deal with IP addressing, making the firewall business a tad less tricky. Each client is assigned a unique ID to connect to with an optional password.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have used fileman in the past, it allows you to share and manage a directory on a linux box via a web interface. Supports passwords and access control.

[image]

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/products/fileman